# How to make p and h3 tag begin at the same height?

Tags: html, css

When I use a `h3` and a `p` tag on the same line, the `p` tag begins at an upper height:

```css
body {
  font-size: 4.5vh;
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

header {
  position: relative;
}

#banner {
  float: left;
  color: #C93756;
}

#account {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h3 id="banner">samplewebsite.com</h3>
    <p id="account">Sign In</p>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Why does this happen and how do I make the two tags appear at the same level?

Comment: Try adjusting them with margins and paddings. For example, add more margin-top to p.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `h3` usually is higher than a `p` element due to the font-size and according line-height and margin settings. Floated elements are aligned at their top, which due to the different overall height of the elements results in what you see in your example.

Use `display: inline-block;` instead of `float` - that aligns them at their baseline by default.

```css
body{
 font-size:4.5vh;
    height:100%;
    width:90%;
    position: relative;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
header {
    position: relative;
}

#banner {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #C93756;
}

#account {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   <h3 id="banner">samplewebsite.com</h3>
   <p id="account">Sign In</p>
  </header>
 </body>

</html>
```

Alternate solution after additional question in comment:

You can use `display: flex` onthe parent element using the following settings to align both elements along their baseline at the left and right margin of the parent element.

`justify-content: space-between;` does the left/right distribution (for two elements, as in this case) and `align-items: baseline;` does the vertical alignment. You don't need any special settings for the children elements in this case.

```css
body{
 font-size:4.5vh;
    height:100%;
    width:90%;
    position: relative;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: baseline;
}

#banner {
    color: #C93756;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   <h3 id="banner">samplewebsite.com</h3>
   <p id="account">Sign In</p>
  </header>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The reason I was using float was because I wanted to align the sign in text to the right using float: right. Is there any way by which I can keep the baselines aligned and still align my sign in text to the right?

Comment: yes, there is: please note the second solution I added to my question

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because `<h3>` is getting `font-size: 1.17em` from the browser's default styles, while `<p>` is getting `font-size: 4.5vh` from your styles.

If you want your `<h3>` instead to inherit `font-size` from body, you have to specify that with `#banner {font-size: inherit;}`.

```css
body {
  font-size: 4.5vh;
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

header {
  position: relative;
}

#banner {
  float: left;
  color: #C93756;
  font-size: inherit;
}

#account {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h3 id="banner">samplewebsite.com</h3>
    <p id="account">Sign In</p>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should explain your solution rather than just post the code.